# Stripe recurring/subscription billing best design/practices?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, payment, stripe-payments

I'm coming off putting together my first site with stripe, but I feel like I could have designed my stripe integration much better than I had. The main issues that I came across were, how do I maintain the state of the stripe account (trialing and past due etc) what are the important webhooks (and the best ways to deal with all the events), and how much data should i be duplicating in my database, and how much should i just pull from Stripe database.

Would love to throw some ideas around on what would be best. 
For reference I developed my site in Ruby on rails, deployed to heroku, used send grid heroku add on to send email notifications about bills, late payments, etc.

Also for those using stripe on RoR here are some good resources that I used (though I haven't found one that really covers recurring/subscription billing with stripe):

RailsCast:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/288-billing-with-stripe

Ofcourse the stripe documentation and api:

- https://stripe.com/docs
- https://stripe.com/docs/api

This little piece of code for webhooks/mailing

- https://github.com/boucher/stripe-webhook-mailer/blob/master/mailer.rb

Answer (score 5):

With regards to duplication - I chose to only store the CustomerKey on my User records locally.  Everything else, Invoices, Transactions, etc is all stored in Stripe.  IMO best not to attempt to keep parity between both systems - at best you'll have duplicate data, at worst, you'll cause all kinds of headaches by not being in sync...

Comment: Huh I tried not to keep parity between but I wanted to use the status of the account to display error messages on page load, but calls to stripe were taking too long to get the status, and thus page load took a long time...

Comment: What about caching Stripe calls? Page load issues will only occur the first time an API call is executed. Subsequent calls are pulled out from cache

Comment: @ChristianFazzini  I know it's been a couple of years but I assume you're talking about Stripe.js for these calls and a cache, or is there some kind of server-side cache that can be used?

Answer (score 1):

The [SaaS Rails Kit](http://railskits.com/saas/) (that I created) integrates with stripe by just storing the card info with stripe (not setting up a recurring charge), getting back the token, then billing the token with a daily cron job when people's accounts come due.

A couple of benefits to this approach include not having to worry about webhooks / keeping the two systems in sync and being able to do metered billing in addition to a flat monthly fee.

Comment: interesting so you basically manually handle everything on your end

Comment: Why would you set up cron jobs to handle this when Stripe already has recurring/subscription billing as functionality?

Comment: i am googeling for a solution since like 2 hours. Each resource i find there is a comment from you somewhere.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that I don't think this answer should be down voted. In stripe if you need to create Layaway payments which stripe doesn't offer you Have To use this approach. I know because I did it and had spoke to stripe staff about my options for implementing it.

Comment: @JM4 what about calculated amount  , for example a saas platform where it is billed according to users usage based on a monthly plan he choose (prepaid). In such scenarios  we can't use  recurring/subscription billing,  is  there a better solution than cron for such situations?

Comment: @JoelJoseph You can handle this scenario using Stripe's recurring billing... Stripe will send you a hook when the monthly invoice is created. You have a few hours to add more invoice items (charges) to that invoice before Stripe will attempt to charge the card for the invoice. This is exactly how I implemented overage charges at [Honeybadger](https://www.honeybadger.io).